# why can't I align my text and the button?

Tags: html, css

[image]

why do my text and button have some additional space in the blue content area and I can't align them in my page. How can I solve this?

this is my html code:

```
<div class="item-container">
  <span class="item">过去一年总结(15分)</span>
  <input type="button" class="score-input">
</div>
```

this is my css code:

```
.score-input{
   width:50px;
  margin-left:30%;
}
.item-container{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size:1rem;
  margin-top:10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Additional space ?

Comment: I guess the OP means the space above the _span.item_. If so please provide the code for the container of this elements.

Comment: yes, do you see the button in the blue content area have some addition space in the bottom.

Comment: can't reproduce - https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/QgdVBv

Answer (score 5):

`span` is an `inline element` so you need to change there `display` and using `vertical-align`, align them to center of parent div.

> The vertical-align CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an
>   inline or table-cell box.
>
> vertcial-align:middle Aligns the middle of the element with the baseline plus half
>   the x-height of the parent.

If you console the display of button then you find it as display `inline-block`, so on that too you can use `vertical-align` and align text to the center of parent div.

```css
#b {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: blue;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.score-input {
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="b">
  <span class="item">过去一年总结15分</span>
  <input type="button" class="score-input">
</div>
```